# SVG to PNG in plugin code - python

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, convert, svg, png

I am making a plugin and what I want to do is display a preview of image in widget. I have previews saved as SVG files. I found a way to show it in plugin window but I must convert them to PNG first. Is there any easy way to convert from SVG to PNG in python/pyqgis?

I found something about cairo, but I don't get how to use it in my plugin code. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to use the cairo library

> $ python3
>   import cairosvg
>   cairosvg.svg2pdf(url='image.svg',  write_to='image.pdf')

**reference :**
http://cairosvg.org/